# How to open cmd using Selenium for Typescript

Tags: typescript, selenium, cmd, command-line-interface

I need to put a set command in cmd before running a script which is writtern using Selenium for typescript.

Is there any way to open command line interface from the script (in before()) so that when I run the script, the script will automatically open the cmd, put the set command in cmd and then will continue with the rest of the execution of the script?

The set command is to set the environment variables, browser type, etc

Comment: Why can't you use the configuration file to handle the browser and environment and what ever the items that you want to push into environment variables.

Comment: Can you give me an example if possible?